# Не отображаются фото в библиотеке медиафайлов

Tags: wordpress

В целях экономии места на сервере отказался от хранения исходных фотографий так как весят по 30-50 мегабайт. В сети нашел такое решение чтобы после создания нужный превьюшеки оригинальный исходник фотки удалялся.

В шаблон внедирил этот код

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'txt_domain_delete_fullsize_image');

function txt_domain_delete_fullsize_image($metadata)
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit($upload_dir['basedir']) . $metadata['file'];
    $deleted = unlink($full_image_path);

    return $metadata;
}
```

Всё замечательно оригинальный исходни не хранится на сервере, но тут теперь очередная проблема в библиотеке медиафайлов перестали отображается фотогрфии. Как можно заставить wp отображать превью фото?

[image: Не отображаются фото в библиотеке медиафайлов]

Comment: 1. Картинки надо готовить ДО заливки, а не тащить на сайт всякую хрень из интернетов. Корявый вариант, но много лучше твоего  - использовать плагины для оптимизации графики.
2. см исходный код страницы.

Comment: SeVlad Увы это онанизм! Прочитайте вопрос внимательно, а про оптимизацию графики я не спрашивал.

Comment: Так не занимайся онанизмом! Ты вот исходный код не знаешь как посмотреть, а сайты берёшься делать.. Ещё и огрызаешься вместо того что бы послушать тех, кто этим занимается много лет.